# 2D Fourier transform of characteristic function of stripe on xy plane

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, transformation

Given a stripe $X$ on the xy-plane, namely  $X\subset\mathbb{R}^2$, with $X=\{(x,y)\,|\; mx-\frac{1}{2}t \le y \le mx + \frac{1}{2}t$} and its "characteristic" function 
$$
f(x,y) = \begin{cases}
  1, & \text{if } (x,y) \in X, \\
  0, & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$
What is the Fourier-transform 
$$
\mathcal{F}[f](u,v) = \frac{1}{2 \pi}\iint_{-\infty}^{\infty}
 f(x,y) e^{i(ux+vy)}dxdy$$
of this function?

I have attempted the special case $m=0$ (a stripe around the x-axis). I have constructed it from a linear combination of two Heaviside functions $\Theta(x)$:
$$ f(x,y) = \frac{1}{2}[\Theta(y+\frac{t}{2}) + \Theta(-y+\frac{t}{2}) ]  * 1$$ 
With 
$$\mathcal{F}[\Theta](u)=\frac{i}{u\sqrt{2\pi}} + \frac{\pi}{2}\delta(u)$$
the linearity of $\mathcal{F}$ and the shift property I get
$$
\pi \delta(u) \delta(v) + \frac{\delta(u) \sin(\frac{tv}{2})}{v}
$$

How to best tackle the general case $m\ne0$? Can one use something like a coordinate transformation (rotation of the plane)?

Comment: Arguably, the simplest thing would just be to pick an appropriate linear transformation to coordinates $(X,Y)$ such that you get the $m=0$ case back in the new coordinates.

Comment: What's the $a$ in $\sin \frac{av}{2}$ supposed to be?

Comment: Typo, corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following up on my comment, suppose we switch to coordinates $(x',y')=(x,y-mx)$. Then the stripe becomes $X'=\{(x',y')|-\frac12 t\leq y' \leq \frac12t\}$ and the Fourier transform takes the form

$$\mathcal{F}[f](u,v) = \frac{1}{2 \pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
 f(x',y') e^{i(ux'+v(y'+mx'))}dx'dy'=\frac{1}{2 \pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
 f(x',y') e^{i(u+mv)x'+ivy'}dx'dy'$$
with $f(x',y')=\frac{1}{2}[\Theta(y'+\frac{t}{2}) + \Theta(-y'+\frac{t}{2}) ]  * 1$.

This is the same as above, except with $(u,v)\to (u+mv,v)$. So the result for the case $m\neq 0$ is
$$
\pi \delta(u+mv)\delta(v) + \frac{\delta(u+mv)\sin(\frac{t}{2}v)}{v},
$$
which simplifies to 
$$
\pi \delta(u)\delta(v) + \frac{\delta(u+mv)\sin(\frac{t}{2}v)}{v}.
$$

Comment: That would yield $$
\pi \delta(u+mv) \delta(v) + \frac{\delta(u+mv) \sin(\frac{tv}{2})}{v}
$$.

Comment: @Franky_GTH Right. Probably the simplest way to verify it is just to take the inverse Fourier transform and check that it gives back the correct form. This is a task made simple by all the delta-functions. (On that last note, I think the first term can be simplified to $\pi\delta(u)\delta(v)$ since $f(u,v)\delta(v)=f(u,0)\delta(v)$.)

Comment: May I add the result and edit your answer, or would you prefer completing it?

Comment: The former is fine.

Comment: @Franky_GTH Strange. But I've gone and accepted the edit.